# Problems running MS Office 2016 after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: macos, ms-office

I updated to the new OS so that I could load Microsoft Office 2016 for MAC as my current OS did not support 2016.  Now when I open excel or word, I get

> Microsoft Excel wants to use your confidential information stored in "Microsoft Identity xxxxxxxxx" in your Keychain.  Do you want to allow access to this item?
>
> Always Allow - Deny -Allow

I have always selected Deny in the past and it would go away.  Now it won't go away and it won't quit out of the program as I must always Force Quit the Microsoft application, whether Word or Excel.

How can I get past this dialogue?

Comment: This site works better if you stick to one question per post. I've edited out one of the questions, feel free to ask it seperately.

Comment: Also, why do you not want to click "Allow"?

Answer (score 2):

If you click deny, it won't go away and it can not update your previous Office 2016 identity.

> How can I get past this dialogue?

Always Allow and it will disappear.